# how can we call the display method in interface from main method

Tags: java, interface

Below find the program I tried out,

```
public interface MyInterface{  
    public default void display() {
        System.out.println("display method of MyInterface");
    }
}

public class InterfaceExample implements MyInterface{
    public void display() {
         System.out.println("display method of class");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        InterfaceExample obj = new InterfaceExample();
        obj.display();
    }
}
```

i want to call the `display()` method in interface from `main` method

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Within `public interface InterfaceExample {}`, you can do this. Outside of that, **this is not possible**.

Within the class, you can do: `MyInterface.super.display();`.

You can make a helper method if you must:

```
public class InterfaceExample implements MyInterface{
    public void display() {
        System.out.println("display method of class");
    }

    public void originalDisplay() {
        MyInterface.super.display();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        InterfaceExample obj = new InterfaceExample();
        obj.originalDisplay();
    }
}
```

But what if you don't 'control' the `InterfaceExample.java` source file and you can't add that method?

Then there is nothing in the java language that lets you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in three ways, first let's see the interface.

```
public interface MyInterface{
    public default void display() {
        System.out.println("display method of MyInterface");
    }
}
```

and the first way is,

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        MyInterface myInterface = new MyInterface() {
            @Override
            public void display() {
                System.out.println("display method in main");
            }
        };
        myInterface.display();
    }
}
```

This will create the `object` from the interface in the `main` method, and while we initiating the object creation, we define the interface method as well.
the output will be `display method in main`

and the second way is,

```
public class Main implements  MyInterface{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Main main = new Main();
        main.display();
    }
}
```

and here we call the default interface method by creating a `Main` class object and calling the `display()` method.
the output will be `display method of MyInterface`

The third way is,

```
public class Main implements  MyInterface{

    @Override
    public void display(){

        System.out.println("display method in main");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Main main = new Main();
        main.display();
    }
}
```

Here we override the interface method and then we create an object of `Main` and run `display()` method.
the output will be, `display method in main`